# Loading arbitrary javascript into Mongo through Java, to be called later

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

It is simple to embed the functions directly,

```
MapReduceOutput out = coll.mapReduce("function() { ... }", 
"function( year, values ) { ... }", 
null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
```

But if I have a .js file like this

```
func = function(i) { ... }

m = function() { ...
func (7);
... }

r = function( year, values ) { ...
func (3);
... }
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
coll.LoadSomethingSomeHow(script);

MapReduceOutput out = coll.mapReduce("m", "r", 
null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
```

Where `script` is a string loaded from the js file?  This would make things much more flexible, and allow for cleaner map reduces.

Comment: I don't think so. If not for the external function I'd think you could just store the functions in separate files; with it, you might need to merge the shared JS into each file's JS.

Comment: I had thought of that. It may not be possible to do it this way, but if it is it would be very useful.

Comment: No, this is not possible. File a request on jira.mongodb.org

Comment: I don't think loading some script into MongoDB is possible but you can store your functions on server side, then reuse them later. But you only need to do this once and you can also do it through Java since all you do is to add your function to a special system collection named `js`. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418651/techniques-for-storing-libraries-in-mongodbs-system-js) - however in your case you might consider grouping the functions within an object/namespace:

```
db.system.js.save({_id: 'mr', value: {func: function(i){…}, m: function(){…}, r: function(){…}}});
```

You can then refer to the functions as `mr.func`, `mr.m`, and `mr.r`.  This, however, is just an organizational convenience - @Umut correctly points to `db.system.js`.  If your library relies on `prototype`, you could write an initialization routine to bootstrap it - however this could be costly since the closure context may be lost across iterations of the map/reduce, requiring repeated initialization.